# Autofill form contents when redirecting from landing page to full registration page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, registration

I am using the following form on a landing page of domain A to let users make a fast registration through domain B's API.

```
 <form action="https://www.domainb.com/api-register" method="post" class="noajax">

            <input value="" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
            <input value="" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />
            <input value="" id="email" name="email" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />                           
</form>
```

When form is submitted successfully, users are redirected to the full registration page of domain B, using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var baseUrl = "https://www.domainb.com";
   var successReg = function () {
   location.href = "https://www.domainb.com/full-registration-page";
```

};

However, the user's info (full name + email) is not transferred to the full registration page to autofill the full registration form.

What would be the simplest way to achieve that?

Comment: Why not just copy the name on the server in `https://www.domainb.com/api-register` and redirect from the server? Why use JS at all?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your question, how to copy the name on the server on domain b? JS is used because it's included in the example code of the API for redirections after the form is submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems that there was a mistake on the API end and has been fixed. 
Now the registration page captures the info correctly.

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

With location.href you are only redirecting to that page.

If you remove all the js code, and add a submit button to the form, it will work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I already have a submit button:
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />